# EKEventEditViewController start date incorrect

Tags: ios, calendar

I have a EKEvent that I am using with a EKEventEditViewController to add a calendar event in my app. Even though the date is accurate, I get the incorrect time. Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong here..

This is the code to generate the event..

```
EKEvent *addEvent=[EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
addEvent.title=event.title;
NSLog(@"Saving Event... %@",[event.date description]);
addEvent.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
addEvent.startDate= event.date;
NSLog(@"Event Date... %@",[addEvent.startDate description]);
addEvent.endDate=[addEvent.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:600];
[addEvent setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
addEvent.alarms=[NSArray arrayWithObject:[EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-3600]];
```

My device's timezone is set to 'Port Louis, Mauritius'.

My console output is..

```
Saving Event... 2012-12-19 20:00:00 +0000
Event Date... 2012-12-19 20:00:00 +0000
```

But in the EKEventEditViewController, my start date shows `Thu,20 Dec 0:00.`

Comment: Is your event at 8pm GMT or 8pm MUT (GMT+4)?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the event at "2012-12-19 20:00:00 +0000" (i.e. 8pm GMT) will take place in Maritius at midnight. You're asking the user in Mauritius to add it to their calendar, so it's going to show the event date in the device's local timezone, midnight.

If the event is taking place at 8pm in Mauritius, then your original time is incorrect, because you're saying it's at 8pm GMT. If you're saying that the event is really taking place at 8pm GMT (midnight in Mauritius), then the `EKEventEditViewController` is just going to show the time according to the local timezone, midnight.

If the user has [turned on timezone support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4576?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), when they pull up the event in the Calendar app, it will show the timezone you specified when you created the even. If they haven't turned on timezone support, it will just show it in the local timezone (adjusting the start time as it should).

Unfortunately, unlike the calendar app, it appears that `EKEventEditViewController` will not show the timezone but rather displays it in local time, even if the user has turned on timezone support. It does not appear to support this timezone feature, even though it will be correct when they look at their calendar. At least the event is stored with the appropriate timezone information.